# Reason for segmentation fault in this snippet of code

Tags: c, linked-list

Question: Write a function `Duplicates()` that takes a list containing integers, and returns the list after removing all duplicate entries from the list.

Thus given the list `20, 25, 25, 30, 40, 45, 45, 45, 60`, it should return `20, 25, 30, 40, 45, 60`. * tried out this code which is giving segmentation fault.*

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct node{
    int d;
    struct node* next;
}node;

typedef node* list;

void printList(list a)
{
    while(a!=NULL)
    {
        printf("  %d",a->d);
        a=a->next;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int i,flag,n,v;
    list head,tail,new,a,taila,b,c;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    scanf("%d",&v);
    tail=head=NULL;
    head=(list)malloc(sizeof(node));
    head->d=v;
    head->next=NULL;
    tail=head;
    for(i=2;i<=n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&v);
        new=(list)malloc(sizeof(node));
        new->d=v;
        new->next=NULL;
        tail->next=new;
        tail=new;
    }
    printf("Before working \n");
    printList(head);
    printf("After working \n");
    a=(list)malloc(sizeof(node));
    taila=NULL;
    a->d=head->d;
    a->next=NULL;
    taila->next=a;
    taila=a;
    b=head;
    for(i=2;i<=n;i++)
    {
        c=head;
        while(c!=b)
        {
            if(c->d==b->d)
                flag++;
            c=c->next;
        }
        if(flag==0)
        {
            new=(list)malloc(sizeof(node));
            new->d=b->d;
            new->next=NULL;
            taila->next=new;
            taila=new;
        }

        b=b->next;
    }
    printList(a);


    return 1;
}
```

Comment: nobody will answer this question. At least show the error you are getting, preferrably show what you have done to try to fix it

Comment: Perhaps if you told us what the error is, we might be able to help you finish your homework. But since it is homework, one of the MOST IMPORTANT lessons, if not THE most important lesson in all of programming, is how to debug your code.

Comment: it also looks like the top of the code is chopped off

Comment: The program stops unexpectedly as the inputs is given.Could you Please check what might be the cause for that.

Comment: This is the entire code

Comment: The error seems to occur while working with the second loop after printing After working as when the code below is commented it works fine as normal linked list.

Comment: @user216064: Your variable names are terrible, and it makes it exceptionally difficult to follow your code.

Comment: @sharth for convenience check // head, tail are meant for input list being taken. a and taila is meant to find out the duplicate list as instructed. c is mere an intermediate variable which is initialised everytime with pointer location of head(the first list) till it reaches b(each time b points to the next element to head).

Comment: OMG, this is like reading ancient Fortran77 code.  Please use descriptive variable names.  In a week when you look at this again, you will thank yourself!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For logic as far as what I understood, you need to remove some flaws then your logic might work. try this one out :
       for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {
            flag=0;
            c=head;
            while(c!=b)
            {
                if(c->d==b->d)
                    flag++;
                c=c->next;
            }
            if(flag==0 && i==1)
            {
                a=(list)malloc(sizeof(node));
                a->d=b->d;
                a->next=NULL;
                taila=a;
            }
            else if(flag==0)
            {
                new=(list)malloc(sizeof(node));
                new->d=b->d;
                new->next=NULL;
                taila->next=new;
                taila=new;
            }

```
        b=b->next;
    }
```

Comment: I should have worked a little more. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the idea you want to accomplish is creating a new Linked List that will have a new Node added to it every time you see a value in your input Linked List that isn't in your result Linked List.

To accomplish this, try walking from the beginning of the input Linked List, H, with something like this:

```
create return and temp nodes;
int length = 0;
while(temp -> next != NULL){
   ...walk the input list...
   for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
      ...walk return list checking temp's payload...
      if(payload seen){break;}
      ...if not seen then add a new node to the return list and increment length...     
   }
   temp = temp -> next;
}
return returnList;
```

If you're OK with the concepts here and need more specific help let me know. It sounded like you were having a hard time conceiving of how to start.

Comment: sorry but i didn't get this well. is...walk the input list... to calculate length and payload?

Comment: It's a generic instruction. 'Walk the List' means start at the head and move to the tail. Trying to give you the idea without writing the code for you. You want to Iterate through the input list and each time you move to a new node in the input list, you iterate over the entire return list (which, please recall, is the list of unique values). When you see a new value, you put it in a new node at the tail of the return list

Answer (score 0):

`for(i=2;i<=n;i++)`

in your input area is not correct. You want to accept `n` inputs?  Then use:

`for(i=0;i<n;i++)`

So that you do indeed receive 'n' inputs.

For your list adding:

`tail->next=new;
tail=new;`

Isn't going to do what you want either.  Why even have a tail pointer?  Most lists are built 'backwards' from the head pointer: Basically create a node, have the current head->next update to it, then set the new node as head with a NULL next.

Heck, a very easy google search "Linked List C code" yielded 100s of results you could use as examples, but don't you dare use them directly or your teacher will fail you for cheating.

I could continue about single letter variable names, no error checking on malloc/ scanf, etc. but it would be a waste of time for now.  For now, fix your input loop and look at some other single linked list code and try again.

Comment: earlier i had already accepted 1 variable hence the loop just includes to have n-1 variables. Besides it works perfectly when the content below "After working " are commented. It would be kind if you may help me debug it of the error i have made that it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node{
    int d;
    struct node* next;
}node;

typedef node* list;

void printList(list a){
    while(a!=NULL){
        printf("%d ", a->d);
        a=a->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void drop_list(list a){
    if(a){
        drop_list(a->next);//Processing in the loop is better
        free(a);
    }
}

void Duplicates(list root){
    node *curr, *tmp;
    curr = root;
    if(!curr)
        return ;
    tmp = curr->next;
    if(!tmp)
        return;
    while(tmp){
        if(curr->d != tmp->d){
            curr = curr->next;
            curr->d = tmp->d;
        }
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    drop_list(curr->next);
    curr->next = NULL;
}

node *new_node(int value){
    list node = malloc(sizeof(*node));
    node->d = value;
    node->next = NULL;
    return node;
}

int main(){
    int data[] = { 20, 25, 25, 30, 40, 45, 45, 45, 60 };
    list head, tail;
    int i, n = sizeof(data)/sizeof(*data);

    tail = head = new_node(data[0]);
    for(i=1;i < n;i++)
        tail = tail->next = new_node(data[i]);

    printf("Before working \n");
    printList(head);

    Duplicates(head);

    printf("After working \n");
    printList(head);

    drop_list(head);
    return 1;
}
//
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you must remove
      taila->next=a; in the sequence
      a->next=NULL;
      taila->next=a;
      taila=a; 
Here you are trying to call the node which is not declared yet as taila itself is null. You might try it after removing that statement.

Comment: The code is rid of the earlier issue. Still output is wrong so might be the logic is wrong. Thanks for your answer. It is helpful.

Comment: For logic as far as what I understood, you need to remove some flaws then your logic might work. try this one out
for(i=1;i<=n;i++){ flag=0;c=head;
            while(c!=b){ if(c->d==b->d) flag++;
                c=c->next;}
            if(flag==0 && i==1){ a=(list)malloc(sizeof(node));
                a->d=b->d;
                a->next=NULL;
                taila=a;}
            else if(flag==0){   new=(list)malloc(sizeof(node));
             new->d=b->d;
             new->next=NULL;
             taila->next=new;
             taila=new;}
            b=b->next;
        }